# programmatically adding textview

Tags: ios, view

Usually I do all of the creation of views in storyboard but now I need to add a view via code and although I understand the very basics of doing one, I need some help on how I go about setting up views but more than that I need to get them placed inside and existing view and also create multiple items. So I will have a parent UIScrollView and inside of that one I need to be able to create up to x additional blocks each block containing two lables and one textview. Something along these lines

I can use the storyboard to create the Parent ScrollView

ParentSCROLLVIEW

child_1_block

lable_1_1

label_1_2

textview_1

child_2_block

lable_2_1

label_2_2

textview_2

child_3_block

lable_3_1

label_3_2

textview_3

child_4_block

lable_4_1

label_4_2

textview_4

.
.
.

child_x_block

lable_x_1

label_x_2

textview_x

I am trying to create just a single one now but I am not sure of the syntax to place it inside of an existing scrollview currently it is going into the main view working on that right now. The other confusing this I have been thinking about is teh creation of a dynamic amount of the same type of objects are is the object name determined if it is going to be dynamic

```
UITextView *newTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, size.height + 16)];
```

Currently I use this to create a new textview but I will need to do the same thing for multiple entities

such as *newTextView1, *newTextView2, *newTextView3, *newTextView4, ..., *newTextViewX

Am I able to construct a string with the appended number and then use that string as the name of the object I need to create...never did that before so I am not sure but I have a feeling I would see errors

I am hoping some one could show me some sample code or point me in the right direction or even suggest what the correct terms I can search for...anything would be helpful

Jeff

Comment: found the insert subview information so I can now work on that but the dynamic names is still an issue I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't give dynamic names to instances.
What you can do, is give them different tags, in case they subclassing from UIView (Like UITextView).

Run this in a loop:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame....];
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
myTextView.tag = loopIndexInt; // This is where you put your dynamic number.
```

Now, In order to retrieve a specific UITextView by it's tag, do:

```
UITextView *textView = [self.view viewWithTag:5]; // in order to get textView with tag number 5.
```

Anyway, it really depends on what you're trying to do.